# Using list items inside component - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using bootstrap-vue and its list items:

```
<b-nav pills>
  <b-nav-item v-for="item in items">{{ text }}</b-nav-item>
</b-nav>
```

I want to achieve the following thing:

When i click on a certain item, it would get an active state (there's built-in directive `:active`, if it's returns `true`, then it gets an active class), however if i click on another item, the previously clicked item should stay as active either, and new one clicked should be active either. So i've decided to use a component with it's own variable to toggle an active state. But i've faced the problem inside a component, because it must have a root `div`, so i'm forced to use it this way:

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-nav-item :active="selectedCategory">{{ category.price }} ₸</b-nav-item>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Category',

  data () {
    return {
      selectedCategory: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Main template after adding the component**

```
<b-nav pills>
  <Category v-for="item in items"/>
</b-nav>
```

As you can see, i've used top level `div` that breaks out my layout.

Here's the questions:

1. How can i solve the problem with top level `div` inside my component? So my list item won't break
2. is it right decision to use a component in my case?
3. Should an `:active` prop be in component or in main template?

Comment: Have you tried `span` instead of `div`? Span is in-line and might not break

Comment: `span` works, but it's all about semantics, is it possible to avoid junking my html markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a class to `b-nav-item` (e.g., named "nav-item"), and style its `display` to be [`inline-block`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp):

```
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwrop08rwo?module=src/components/Category.vue)